# Cant read info.plist file

Tags: xcode, info.plist

I have made some changes in info.plist file by opening in text editor and saved it. after that my app is not reading the info.plist file.

**Error**:

```
couldn't parse contents of '/Users/apple/Desktop/Chicos Swift/Chicos Pizza/Chicos Pizza/Info.plist'
:The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format
```

**Screen shots**:

[enter image description here][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkSmn.png

Comment: Open the file again and fix the issue (probably a corrupted or badly balanced tag).

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>    This syntax I have added

Comment: The lines look correct. But they **must not** be inserted right after another `key` line. Check that. It's always key - value - key - value... And check also if all `<` and `>` are still there.

Comment: I have removed that one and again tried  to build. but same error is there

Comment: Finally it worked @vadian after discard all previous changes. Thanks to guide

Answer (score 0):

Check it carefully, there is probably a fat fingered character in there somewhere.

Or try posting the entire file.

Comment: i have added the App transportation security

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>